# c# when I use only TryGetValue on dictionary.. it's thread-safe?

Tags: c#, dictionary, thread-safety

When init-time, I added some values to my dictionary.

After that, I only need to TryGetValue.

in this case, I need to lock for TryGetValue?

Comment: I think it should be thread-safe, but, please, for concurrent scenarios use concurrent data structures.

Comment: Read on always thread safe, it's write which create a trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's thread safe if you only read it/ use `TryGetValue`:

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` **can support multiple readers concurrently,
>   as long as the collection is not modified**. Even so, enumerating
>   through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In
>   the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the
>   collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the
>   collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing,
>   you must implement your own synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Reading a **Dictionary** after population is thread safe.

Use the **ConcurrentDictionary** Class to ensure thread safety for use cases when you need to read and write.

**From MSDN:**

> Represents a thread-safe collection of key/value pairs that can be
>   accessed by multiple threads concurrently.
>
> Namespace:
>   System.Collections.Concurrent Assembly:  mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)

[Link to MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx).